# How to change the font of string on webview

Tags: iphone

I am making an iPhone app in which on one of the `UIWebView` I am displaying a string i.e. "Example". I want to change it's font. I have used html concept also to change its font but by using this it is changing all other string which are on that `UIWebView`. But I want to change only "Example" font and size.
 How can I do this. If anyone know about this please help me.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with following code, Assuming that you are putting that string between  element and it is the first on the page. If it is not like that adjust as per your convenience.

```
NSString *strFontIncrease = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].style.webkitTextSizeAdjust= '%f%%'",yourFontValue];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:strFontIncrease];
[strFontIncrease release];
```

Check out and let me know if any doubt.

Comment: My Code Snippet for the application is as follows :     NSMutableString *exampleHTMLString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:cssString];
NSString *exampletitle = @"Example";
[exampleHTMLString appendFormat:@"%@",exampletitle];
[exampleHTMLString appendString:@"</div></body>"];
       
       [mQuestionWebView loadHTMLString:exampleHTMLString baseURL:baseURL];                                                           Please look in the code and give me solution related to it.

Comment: @Minkle plz post full html code in your question itself so that I can checkout for that.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try somthing like :

```
  <font size="5" face="arial" color="red">
        This paragraph is in Arial, size 5, and in red text color.
  </font>
```

Visit: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_fonts.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
test test test <span style="background: blue; color: white; font-size:30px;">test test test</span>test test test
```

This is not iPhone programing related. :D